# How to set CONFIG_PATH in Heroku buildpack

Tags: bash, heroku, ffmpeg, buildpack

Before I elaborate on the problem, I should let you know that I've successfully installed ffmpegthumbnailer on heroku's bash (heroku run bash).

I'm trying to build ffmpegthumbnailer using a custom Heroku buildpack I've written, but when I run ./configure && make install in the bin/compile buildpack file, ffmpegthumbnailer tells me that it can't find the ffmpeg libs (util, format, codec, scale) and suggest that I set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH. So I set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH and it still can't seem to find the libraries.

I've tried setting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH every which way. echo export, export, directly set it via PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/app... I've always set it inline with the .configure command. I even set PKG_CONFIG_PATH as a heroku config var, and tried to acces it via the ENV_DIR variable that's passed into the buildpack as the third parameter, but I soon realized that I was simply setting a variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the contents of the file called PKG_CONFIG_PATH, i.e. I was setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/app/vendor..., which I've already done!! None of these have worked. Also, as you can see in the compile file and the log, echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH prints the correct path.

What more debugging can i do? What is going on?

Below is my bin/compile buildpack file, and the log after I deploy my app to heroku.

```
#!/bin/sh

indent() {
  sed -u 's/^/       /'
}

echo "-----> Install ffmpeg-thumbnailer"
BUILD_DIR=$1
VENDOR_DIR="vendor"
DOWNLOAD_URL="https://ffmpegthumbnailer.googlecode.com/files/ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0.8.tar.gz"

echo "DOWNLOAD_URL = " $DOWNLOAD_URL | indent

cd $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $VENDOR_DIR
cd $VENDOR_DIR
curl -L --silent $DOWNLOAD_URL | tar xz
cd ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0.8/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/app/vendor/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/"
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
./configure --prefix /app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer && make install

echo "exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH" | indent
PROFILE_PATH="$BUILD_DIR/.profile.d/ffmpeg-thumbnailer.sh"
mkdir -p $(dirname $PROFILE_PATH)
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:vendor/ffmpeg-thumbnailer/bin"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:vendor/ffmpeg-thumbnailer/lib"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
```

And my heroku deployment log...

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 311 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg
=====> Detected Framework: ffmpeg
-----> Install ffmpeg
       DOWNLOAD_URL =  http://flect.github.io/heroku-binaries/libs/ffmpeg.tar.gz
       exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/johnklawlor/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-thumbnailer
=====> Detected Framework: ffmpeg
-----> Install ffmpeg-thumbnailer
HERE COMES PKG_CONFIG!
/app/vendor/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig
       DOWNLOAD_URL =  https://ffmpegthumbnailer.googlecode.com/files/ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0.8.tar.gz
/app/vendor/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking whether /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64 accepts --as-needed... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for FFMPEG... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libavutil libavformat libavcodec >= 52.26.0 libswscale) were not met:

No package 'libavutil' found
No package 'libavformat' found
No package 'libavcodec' found
No package 'libswscale' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables FFMPEG_CFLAGS
and FFMPEG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
       exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

Comment: Is there anybody out there? (who gets this reference?)

Comment: Though I was unable to answer this question (because I still do not understand why PKG_CONFIG_PATH is not being set or read properly during the ./configure process), I was successful in deploying ffmpegthumbnailer on heroku via a buildpack. Please refer to [heroku-buildpack-ffmpegthumbnailer](https://github.com/johnklawlor/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-thumbnailer) if this is your ultimate goal.

Comment: And if you have an answer to my question, please let me know! I suspect it's a glitch of sorts, but that's such a poor explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to a non-existing directory. Note that https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg creates the directory `$BUILD_DIR/vendor/ffmpeg` on the build dyno, and not `/app/vendor/ffmpeg`, and `$BUILD_DIR` is something like `/tmp/build_<hash>`.

If you change your variable assignment to

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$BUILD_DIR/vendor/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig"
```

then `configure` will find the libraries.

However, there's another point. For this, it's necessary to know that what's in `$BUILD_DIR` after the build is your application slug and  will be in `/app` on the production dynos. Thus, the path to `ffmpeg` is `$BUILD_DIR/vendor/ffmpeg` during the build, but `/app/vendor/ffmpeg` during production.

Currently, with

```
./configure --prefix /app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer && make install
```

you are installing `ffmpegthumbnailer` to `/app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer` which is outside of your application slug. It is however indeed the location you want it during production, but this means that it must be in `$BUILD_DIR/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer` at the end of the build.

One way to achieve this is to configure and install your things to `/app` and then copy the finished installation directory to `$BUILD_DIR`. Thus, you can do

```
./configure --prefix /app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer && make install
mkdir -p "$BUILD_DIR"/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer
cp -R /app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer/ "$BUILD_DIR"/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer
```

In this way, the path used for `./configure --prefix` is the path valid at runtime (otherwise problems at runtime), ***and*** we have the installation included in our application slug.

Setting `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime is then done as you did:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer/bin"' >>"$PROFILE_PATH"
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer/lib"' >>"$PROFILE_PATH"
```

because these are the paths valid at runtime.

It in fact all boils down to the equation `$BUILD_DIR` *(build) ==* `/app` *(production)*