# Deploying a Python Library with C Dependencies to Heroku

Tags: python, c, linux, docker, heroku

I am having some frustration deploying my project to Heroku. It depends upon a few python libraries for astrological software, which work fine on my local machine. But one of these libraries requires you to download some files and set the path to the downloaded files in order to run, and I think it is failing at this moment in the build process. The library is a Python extension to another library originally written in C. The python library is [here](https://github.com/astrorigin/pyswisseph). I've been looking at some documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker), but I've never built a docker image, and I'm not even sure it would be a solution to my problems. I also thought of adding a new buildpack, but also not sure it would solve the problem. My error is below, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I'm mostly looking for someone to tell me whether my problem could be solved with Docker or otherwise so that I don't waste time going down that path if it won't help. Thank you.

```
Installing collected packages: pyswisseph
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839661+00:00 app[web.1]: Running setup.py install for pyswisseph: started
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839662+00:00 app[web.1]: Running setup.py install for pyswisseph: finished with status 'error'
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839662+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839801+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839814+00:00 app[web.1]: command: /app/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q
/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-djfmycyt
/pyswisseph/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-djfmycyt/pyswisseph/setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-
wheel-vuz1lu7j
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839815+00:00 app[web.1]: cwd: /tmp/pip-install-djfmycyt/pyswisseph/
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839815+00:00 app[web.1]: Complete output (23 lines):
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839816+00:00 app[web.1]: Searching system libswe...
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839816+00:00 app[web.1]: pkg-config not found
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839816+00:00 app[web.1]: Using internal libswe
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839817+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q
/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:454: UserWarning: Normalizing '2.08.00-1' to 
'2.8.0.post1'

2020-05-20T00:01:48.839817+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839818+00:00 app[web.1]: running bdist_wheel
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839818+00:00 app[web.1]: running build
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839818+00:00 app[web.1]: running build_ext
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839818+00:00 app[web.1]: building 'swisseph' extension
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839819+00:00 app[web.1]: creating build
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839819+00:00 app[web.1]: creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839819+00:00 app[web.1]: creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/libswe
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839820+00:00 app[web.1]: creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/swephelp
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839823+00:00 app[web.1]: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare
 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ilibswe -Iswephelp -I/app/.local/share/virtualenvs
/app-4PlAip0Q/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c pyswisseph.c -o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyswisseph.o -std=gnu99
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839824+00:00 app[web.1]: In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/7/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839824+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-

fixed/limits.h:34,
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839825+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m/Python.h:11,
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839825+00:00 app[web.1]: from pyswisseph.c:58:
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839828+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed/limits.h:194:15: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839829+00:00 app[web.1]: #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the
 real one */
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839829+00:00 app[web.1]: ^~~~~~~~~~
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839829+00:00 app[web.1]: compilation terminated.
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839846+00:00 app[web.1]: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839847+00:00 app[web.1]: ----------------------------------------
2020-05-20T00:01:48.839847+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyswisseph
```

EDIT - Here is the example setup.py code that is failing for reference :

```
# Test for pkg-config
has_pkgconfig = False
if swe_detection:
    print('Searching system libswe...')
    try:
        import subprocess
        try:
            subprocess.check_output(['pkg-config'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        except AttributeError: # < Python 2.7
            # detection without pkg-config (or use popen)
            pass
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        has_pkgconfig = True
        print('Found pkg-config')
    except OSError:
        print('pkg-config not found')
        pass
    except ImportError: # Python < 2.4
        pass
    #

# Find libswe-dev
libswe_found = False
if has_pkgconfig:
    try:
        swe_includes = subprocess.check_output(
            ['pkg-config', '--cflags', 'libswe-'+swe_version],
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        swe_libs = subprocess.check_output(
            ['pkg-config', '--libs', 'libswe-'+swe_version],
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        swe_sources = []
        swe_depends = []
        swe_defines = [('PYSWE_DEFAULT_EPHE_PATH',
            '"/usr/share/libswe/ephe2:/usr/share/libswe/ephe"')]
        libswe_found = True
        print('pkg-config found libswe-'+swe_version)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    #

# Another attempt at finding libswe-dev -- without pkg-config
# (pkg-config may be uninstalled but pc file should be in place)
# (and assuming there is only one version installed...)
if ( swe_detection and not libswe_found
    and os.path.isfile( '/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libswe-'+swe_version+'.pc' )):
    swe_includes = ['/usr/include']
    swe_sources = []
    swe_depends = []
    swe_libs = ['swe']
    swe_defines = [('PYSWE_DEFAULT_EPHE_PATH',
        '"/usr/share/libswe/ephe2:/usr/share/libswe/ephe"')]
    print('Found system libswe')
```

Comment: Looks like a few issues. You may need to solve them one-by-one and rerun. One thing that is generic (used by many packages) is the `pkg-config` command is missing.You need to install the package for that. We need to know what _distro_ you have (e.g. fedora, ubuntu, debian, gentoo, mint, suse). Some distros are `rpm` based and use `dnf/yum` to install packages. Others are debian-bases, have `.deb` files and use `apt-get` [or `dpkg`]. ubuntu uses `apt-get`. Then, find the package that has `pkg-config`. fedora (e.g.) do: `dnf install pkgconf-pkg-config` but ubuntu's name is probably different

Comment: After that, `limits.h` is missing (also generic). (e.g.) for fedora, it's in the `glibc-headers` development package. Development packages for a given binary package (e.g.) `xxx` are sometimes of the form: `xxx-devel` for fedora and `xxx-dev` for ubuntu. For example, to install the `SDL2` graphics lib, the binary package is `SDL2` and the dev pkg is `SDL2-devel` [fedora] and ubuntu will be slightly different.

Comment: thank you @CraigEstey . I'm not sure which distro I have. Do you know how I can find out ? I am developing on macOS (Catalina). I've never installed pkg-config or used apt, so I'm not sure how to install those. Im also pasting some of the source code from the library Im trying to use, where it is failing in its setup.py, if that helps.

Comment: it sounds like I might need to set the config path environmental variable on heroku as per this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995788/how-to-set-config-path-in-heroku-buildpack, but im not exactly sure what to set it to.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. I think the build process was getting convoluted because I had a Rails app that was trying to run Python scripts, and I had two different buildpacks that were probably conflicting. I rewrote my app using just Python/Flask (it's just one page so far for testing deployment), and this seems to work (at least I've had no import/build errors). So, for anyone looking at this question, that was my fix. I used pipenv / a Pipfile instead of venv or virtualenv and gunicorn to deploy.